# How to get assertion messages from Nodeos?

Tags: cleos, nodeos, eosjs

When I trigger a failing `eosio_assert` my Nodeos instance outputs something like:

```
2018-08-01T16:45:42.006 thread-0   http_plugin.cpp:476           handle_exception     ] Exception Details: 3050003 eosio_assert_message_exception: eosio_assert_message assertion failure
assertion failure with message: profile already exists
    {"s":"profile already exists"}
    thread-0  wasm_interface.cpp:930 eosio_assert
pending console output:
    {"console":""}
    thread-0  apply_context.cpp:61 exec_one
```

Now I connect via [eosjs](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs#configuration) to the blockchain and get a console error but the assertion message (`profile already exists`) is not present in this output. I already tried setting `verbose` and `debug` in the [eosjs configuration](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs#configuration) but this does not give me the assertion message either. I also looked through the documentation for [Nodeos](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/reference#get_info) and [Cleos](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/reference#cleos-client) and could not find much there as well.

**What is the best way to have Nodeos report assertion error messages or query Nodeos for them?**